# zu oder zur Berühmtheit

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Was ist korrekt?

> Die Schauspielerin kam durch ihre Hauptrolle in diesem Film zu Berühmtheit.

oder

> Die Schauspielerin kam durch ihre Hauptrolle in diesem Film zur Berühmtheit.

Für mich sollte die zweite Form mit *"zur"* richtig sein und von der ersten mit *"zu"* bin ich nicht absolut sicher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Zu Berühmtheit kommen" ist richtig.
Zu etwas kommen hat hier die Bedeutung von erhalten. Genauso kann man z.B. sagen: "Die Schauspielerin kam zu Geld" (und nicht: die Schauspielerin kam zum Geld)

"kommen zur" (zur = zu + der) würde man mit einer Bewegung zu einem Ort oder einer Person benutzen, z.B. ich kam zur Schauspielerin oder ich kam zur Brücke (mit Berühmtheit ergibt diese Verwendung wenig Sinn, deswegen die anderen Beispiele)

Comment: Etwas Erbsenpulerei, aber es geht ja gerade um Sprache: Man wird zur (zu einer) Berühmtheit, wenn man zu Ruhm kommt. Zur Berühmtheit kommen ist falsch - außer man meint, dass man es schafft, eine (andere) Berühmtheit zu treffen (ggf. unter Überwindung von Hindernissen). "Zu Berühmtheit kommen" ist als Synonym zu "zu Ruhm gelangen" m.E. etwas unglücklich formuliert, auch wenn man es antreffen mag.

Answer (score 1):

Geht es um jedes einzelne Wort in den Sätzen, ist nur der erste korrekt. Geht es um mögliche Aussagen, sind beide korrekt - also fast.

Im ersten Satz geht es darum, was die Schauspielerin erhalten hat: [Berühmtheit](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ber%C3%BChmtheit).

Im zweiten Satz geht es darum, was die Schauspielerin wurde: [berühmt](https://www.dwds.de/r/?from=wb&corpus=kern&q=Ber%C3%BChmt+werden&h=1).

Und da liegt auch das *"fast"*:

> Die Schauspielerin *wurde* durch ihre Hauptrolle in diesem Film zur Berühmtheit.